# Question on proof of deformation lemma

Tags: partial-differential-equations

on page  no 479 of partial differential equation (Evans) how the condition (iii) of deformation lemma is satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After $(12)$, Evans concluded that for $u\in H$ and $t\in [0,1]$ $$\tag{1}\frac{d}{dt}I[\eta_t(u)]\leq 0,\ $$

$(1)$ is telling us that the function $v(t)=I[\eta_t(u)]$ for $u$ fixed is non-increasing, which implies that $v(t)\leq v(0)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ or equivalently (remember that $\eta_0(u)=u$) $$I[\eta_t(u)]\leq I[u],\ \forall\ t\in [0,1]$$

Comment: \tag{1}\frac{d}{dt}I[\eta_t(u)]\leq 0,\from the above equation we can tell $I$ is only non-increasing function. then how you told v(t)(=\eta_t(u)) is non-increasing

Comment: Sorry, we have to add a $I$ in the text. I have fixed it

Comment: ya now cleared thank you